# Complex multi machine init setup: suggestions on improving the Lisp code

Tags: org-mode, init-file

I'm trying to configure my org based init file to work on 2 different machines where some of my org file would be accessed remotely. 
For example I want to define within the same config different org capture based on which machine I'm currently on (hostname).

I have this initial code:

```
(when (string= system-name "home")

(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
'("z" "web capture " item
         (file+headline "/home/zeltak/org/files/web/wbookmarks.org" "Temporary Links")
         "%?\nEntered on %U\n \%i\n %a"))
)


(when (string= system-name "work")

(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
'("z" "web capture " item
         (file+headline "/sshx:work:~/org/files/wbookmarks.org" "Temporary Links")
         "%?\nEntered on %U\n \%i\n %a"))
)
```

I have 30 captures like this where I have to reproduce for both machines. I am sure there is a more intelligent way to do this and am looking for suggestions. Perhaps define a Path variable that changes based on machine?

Comment: Please do not sign off posts with "best", "thanks", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea is fine:

```el
(if (string= system-name "home")
    (setq my-org-path "/home/zeltak/org/files/")
  (setq my-org-path "/sshx:work:~/org/files/"))

(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
             '("z" "web capture " item
               (file+headline (expand-file-name "web/wbookmarks.org" my-org-path) "Temporary Links")
               "%?\nEntered on %U\n \%i\n %a"))
```

If you're only going to use `my-org-path` in the context of setting the org-capture-templates list, you could isolate it in a `let` form:

```el
(let ((my-org-path 
       (if (string= system-name "home")
           "/home/zeltak/org/files/"
         "/sshx:work:~/org/files/")))

  (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
               '("z" "web capture " item
                 (file+headline (expand-file-name "web/wbookmarks.org" my-org-path) "Temporary Links")
                 "%?\nEntered on %U\n \%i\n %a")))
```

This has the advantage of not polluting your global name space with `my-org-path` if you're not going to use it after loading your config. Probably not a big deal either way.

Comment: Don't forget to quasiquote in the template within add-to-list.

Comment: great works really well.thx!

Comment: @Dan good point, but not necessary in this case I think. The filename for a template target (i.e., `(concat my-org-path ...)`) may be an elisp form (see the help for `org-capture-templates`), so presumably orgmode knows how to accommodate this behind the scenes. It must be, if the code as written is working for zeltak.

Comment: I would recommend `(expand-file-name "web/wbookmarks.org" my-org-path)` instead of using `concat`, since `expand-file-name` is tailored towards paths.